# How to configure nginx to serve to public

Tags: linux, nginx, server

after much research, I can't find a definitive answer.

I have:
 - a domain with Godaddy
 - nginx 
 - Linux server

How do I configure nginx so that when people go to www.mydomain.com (example), they are served from my own nginx?

I'm looking for a basic approach to purely just set up nginx to serve to the public.

Answer (score 2):

i think u should use docker. İf u use yor docker on amazone. I think, u can set up your ngnix to serve to the public.

if u decide use your nginx with docker on amazone look this page for help.

```
https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/
```

Comment: I have a private server at home